# Doing git svn rebase after using git-subtree

Tags: git, svn, migration, git-svn, git-subtree

**Introduction**

We are moving from Git to SVN using `git-svn`.

We have a single SVN repository with a large directory tree. A project links to other subprojects using relative paths. The simplified example below has a `MainProject` that is dependent on `SharedProject1` and `SharedProject2`

```
SVN
└── trunk
    ├── MainProject 
    ├── SharedProject1
    └── SharedProject2
```

Moving over to Git, we will have one repository per project. We will handle dependencies using `git-subtree`. So the structure for the `MainProject` repository would look like:

```
MainProject
└── Depend
    ├── SharedProject1
    └── SharedProject2
```

**How the git -> svn move is performed**

Each project is cloned to Git repositories using:

```
git svn clone http://server/svn --trunk="trunk/MainProject" MainProject
git svn clone http://server/svn --trunk="trunk/SharedProject1" SharedProject1
git svn clone http://server/svn --trunk="trunk/SharedProject2" SharedProject2
```

In the `MainProject` we add the SharedProject's with git-subtree:

```
git subtree add --prefix "Depend/SharedProject1" path/to/SharedProject1 master --squash
git subtree add --prefix "Depend/SharedProject2" path/to/SharedProject2 master --squash
```

After changing the links in MainProject, everything works fine!

**The problem with git svn rebase**

When some of our developers updates the `MainProject` in the SVN repository, I want to add the changes to the Git repository for MainProject using:

```
git svn rebase
```

But I get the following error:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Squashed 'Depend/SharedProject1/' content from commit fdabd7b
Applying: Squashed 'Depend/SharedProject2/' content from commit 38e8c6f
...
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0002 Squashed 'Depend/SharedProject2/' content from commit 38e8c6f
...
rebase refs/remotes/trunk: command returned error: 1
```

Both `SharedProject1` and `SharedProject2` (but not `MainProject`) has a file `Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs` that git seems to try to merge even though they are not in the same folder.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get it to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

I have another problem, may be related to your problem (yes, after years has passed). On my side the `git svn rebase` tries to rebase the root of a subree directly into the root of the main project (as there was no `--prefix` for the subree or it does ignore it).

That happens after these steps:

1. I try to pull the root and gain the error:

'

```
From https://...
 ! [rejected]        trunk      -> master  (non-fast-forward)
 + 834b7b2...794c965 trunk      -> origin/trunk  (forced update)
```

2. I try to fix previous error by removing this: `.git\svn\refs\remotes\origin\trunk` and refetching the svn: `git svn fetch` (this fix basically works)
3. After the `git svn rebase` the main project root is messed up and contains the root of a subtree.

Seems in your case you have 2 subtrees, where the git tries to merge a file to the same directory (main project root) twice.

I don't know why, but seems `git-svn` somehow either misses information about subtree prefixes or does not take it into account.

To fix that i have to call `git push origin master:trunk` before the `git svn rebase`.